# Angular, bootstrap-ui with requirejs issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap-ui on my angualr project with requirejs.

I think I have it set up correctly however it seems to having some issues - here is my setup -

```
  require.config({
paths: {
    'angular': '//thirdparty/angular/1.3.4/angular.min',
    'underscore': '//thirdparty/underscore/1.6.0/underscore.min',
    'bootstrap-ui' : 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap.min',
    'bootstrap-ui-tpls' : 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min',
},
shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
    'bootstrap-ui-tpls' : {
        deps: ['angular'],
        exports: 'bootstrap-ui-tpls'
    },
    'bootstrap-ui': {
        deps: ['angular','bootstrap-ui-tpls']
    }
}
});
```

- I am assuming you need to add the tpls like so - this may be part of the issue?

Then I just define it in the module I'm using it in like so :

```
define('file.tabs/directive', [
'bootstrap-ui'
], function(bootstrapUi) {
var metaData = {
    moduleName: 'FileTabsDirective',
    componentName: 'FileTabs'
};
angular.module(metaData.moduleName, [
    'ui.bootstrap'
]).directive(metaData.componentName,
```

And so I tried using the tabset bit in the module I am loading it into - and getting this :

```
  load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
   http://localhost:9000/template/tabs/tabset.html
```

so it's looking for the template/tabs/tabset.html - which is definitely not there. Could use some help, this is a bit confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load both libraries, just use the version with the templates. Difference is explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files).